# CKEditor remove style dropdown from toolbar

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, styles, editor

Need a way to remove styles dropdown from ckEditor.

I am able to remove buttons from the toolbar using `removeButtons` option. But was not able to remove **stylesSet** option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the [Styles Combo](http://ckeditor.com/addon/stylescombo) add-on. Put in config.js :

```
config.removePlugins = 'stylescombo';
```